# How to enable CheckBoxField in GridView dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I generate **CheckBoxField** in **GridView** dynamically. but in output the CheckBox is **disabled**.
How to **enable** CheckBox dynamically.
I know if add a TemplateField in GridView markup  my problem is solved but i won't add TemplateField in GridView

ASPX:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(bool));
    DataRow r = dTable.NewRow();
    r[0] = false;        
    dTable.Rows.Add(r);
    r = dTable.NewRow();
    r[0] = true;
    dTable.Rows.Add(r);

    CheckBoxField chkField = new CheckBoxField();
    chkField.DataField = "c1";
    chkField.HeaderText = "CheckBox";
    chkField.ReadOnly = false;
    GridView2.Columns.Add(chkField);
    GridView2.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: It may be GridView is not editable by default. Can you try adding `GridView2.AutoGenerateEditButton=true;` before data binding? It may add an edit column but still you might get a clue of what is happening...

Comment: Why are you adding checkboxfield like this. Can you the purpose may be someone can help you find alternate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put code in the RowDataBound event to enable the checkbox:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GridView2.RowDataBound += GridView2_RowDataBound;

    BindGrid();
}

void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[0].GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell))
    {
        TableCell tc = e.Row.Cells[0];
        if (tc.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)tc.Controls[0];
            if (!(cb == null))
            {
                cb.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(bool));
    DataRow r = dTable.NewRow();
    r[0] = false;
    dTable.Rows.Add(r);
    r = dTable.NewRow();
    r[0] = true;
    dTable.Rows.Add(r);

    //CheckBoxField chkField = new CheckBoxField();
    //chkField.DataField = "c1";
    //chkField.HeaderText = "CheckBox";
    //chkField.ReadOnly = false;
    //GridView1.Columns.Add(chkField);
    GridView2.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Optimize Decker97 answer:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
protected void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(bool));
    DataRow r = dTable.NewRow();
    r[0] = false;
    dTable.Rows.Add(r);
    r = dTable.NewRow();
    r[0] = true;
    dTable.Rows.Add(r);
    GridView2.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        cb.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```